# Покадровая анимация в Android Studio, изменение скорости анимации

Tags: android, анимация

Есть вопрос, на самом деле, это просто частный случай, чтобы понятнее объяснить мой вопрос. Недавно изучаю Студию и не раз натыкался на ситуацию, когда мне нужно изменить какой-либо параметр из xml. На форумах толкового ничего не находил, поэтому как-то решал это дело, пританцовывая с бубном, ибо знаний мало еще. И вот дошло дело у меня до анимаций, на форуме 2012 года вычитал, что лучше делать покадровую анимацию через xml, хотя, возможно, положение дел изменилось. Вот что в xml у меня

```
<animation-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/left0" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/left1" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/left2" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/left3" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/left4" android:duration="250"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/left_full" android:duration="250"/>
```

Это простая зацикленная картинка, в коде получаю свою анимацию так:

```
ImageView animLeft = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.animLeft);
    animLeft.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animleft);
    mAnimationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) animLeft.getBackground();
    mAnimationDrawable.start();
```

Все работает, все красиво. И вот сам вопрос: как я могу изменять длительность анимации. В xml она равна 250мс. Я могу как-то из кода менять эти значения? Если да, то как? Если нет, то подскажите, каким образом лучше создать покадровую анимацию?

UPD
Переписал все, сделал, чтобы можно было менять в коде, где duration объявлен ранее. Но все-таки интересует возможность редактирования xml непосредственно из кода, если возможно такое

```
private void startFrameAnimation() {
    BitmapDrawable frame1 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left0);
    BitmapDrawable frame2 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left1);
    BitmapDrawable frame3 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left2);
    BitmapDrawable frame4 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left3);
    BitmapDrawable frame5 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left4);
    BitmapDrawable frame6 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.left_full);


    mAnimationDrawable = new AnimationDrawable();

    mAnimationDrawable.setOneShot(false);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame1, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame2, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame3, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame4, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame5, DURATION);
    mAnimationDrawable.addFrame(frame6, DURATION);


    manimLeft.setBackground(mAnimationDrawable);

    if (!mAnimationDrawable.isRunning()) {
        mAnimationDrawable.setVisible(true, true);
        mAnimationDrawable.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Изменить длительность показа кадра анимации, уже созданной из ресурсов, нельзя.
Но вы можете создавать такие анимации не в XML, а в коде.

**UPD:** код уже появился в вопросе.